# Navigating to Blazor Server Login page Not working

Tags: .net, blazor

Could someone help explain the issue here? Firing up a Blazor Server app with in-app Identity you get the Register/Login page, which route is `Identity/Account/Login`.

yet, if I put in a button with Blazor's Navigation Manager, I get a nothing found at this address...

```
<Button @onclick="@(() => navigationManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login"))">Go to login</Button>
```

Comment: `Identity/Account/Login` is not a Blazor route it's a server page outside Blazor.  You need to add navigationManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login", true)) to force a hard navigation event, and the server to load the registered path.  The Ideentity stuff is all standard DotNetCore, not Blazor.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis You should add this as an answer as it helped me

Answer (score 1):

Identity/Account/Login is not a Blazor route it's a server page outside Blazor.

You need to add navigationManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login", true)) to force a hard navigation event, and the server to load the registered path. The Ideentity stuff is all standard DotNetCore, not Blazor.